# Get Altitude in App Inventor

Tags: android, app-inventor

I'm using App Inventor. How do get altitude to work using LocationSensor? I'm using a Nexus 4 and I'm successful of getting Lat and Long.

I checked if `LocationSensor.HasAltitude` and it returned `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install [Sensor Kinetics](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.innoventions.sensorkinetics) on your device from Google Play. The app will tell you what your device supports, or doesn't support.

See the [App Inventor Documentation](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/components/sensors.html#LocationSensor) that confirms that the altitude has to be supported by your device for it work.

My LG G2 phone for instance, which is better than the Nexus 5 hardware-wise, has gps (although Sensor Kinetics doesn't mention the gps), a gyroscope sensor, a magnetometer, a gravity sensor, and a bunch of other sensors, but it does not have a pressure sensor, nor an ambient temperature sensor. So the only way I could tell my altitude is by inferring my altitude from my gps location on a map with altitude data (although, this obviously wouldn't give me an accurate reading if I went up the floors in a building, or went up and down in an helicopter).

One device that has a pressure sensor (that I can remember seeing the demo of) is the Xoom. Apparently, its pressure sensor is quite sensitive (although, that information would have to be coupled with a temperature sensor, or current meteorical/geo information, to be able to compute an accurate altitude, and that sensor would give you a false altitude result in a plane's passenger compartment that's pressurized).

Comment: Thanks I got it. It only show altitude if the provider is set to GPS.

Answer (score 0):

make sure, gps is enabled on your device and gps is available as provider, then set `LocationSensor.ProviderName = gps`, also lock the provider: `LocationSensor.ProviderLocked = true`
 
this snippet might help http://puravidaapps.com/snippets1.php#gps

Comment: in this case please mark the answer as accepted, for more info see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)